# Divide a row by another row based on the same Id

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to divide rows which have the same Id by each other and making new rows out of the result.
My dataset looks like this at the moment (in the original dataset there are much more id not only 2):

```
Id  x1  x2  x3  x4
1   50  40  30  20
1   10  5   3   10
2   60  70  40  10
2   5   10  4   2
```

I want my dataset to look like this:

```
Id  x1  x2  x3  x4
1   50  40  30  20
1   10  5   3   10
1   5   8   10  2
2   60  70  40  10
2   5   10  4   2
2   12  7   10  5
```

Does somebody know how I can implement this in R (most preferably with base R)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are there always 2 rows per `Id` ?

Comment: @markus yes there are always 2 rows per Id

Comment: In `base R`, you can do `rbind(df1, cbind(unique(df1[1]), df1[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE),]/df1[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE),]))`

Comment: Check my solution please to see if that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of dealing with this problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~Id,  ~x1,  ~x2,  ~x3,  ~x4,
  1,   50,  40,  30,  20,
  1,   10,  5,   3,   10,
  2,   60,  70,  40,  10,
  2,   5,   10, 4,   2
)

df %>%
  bind_rows(
    df %>%
      group_by(Id) %>%
      mutate(across(.cols = x1:x4, ~ .x / lead(.x))) 
  ) %>%
  arrange(Id) %>%
  drop_na()

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     Id    x1    x2    x3    x4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    50    40    30    20
2     1    10     5     3    10
3     1     5     8    10     2
4     2    60    70    40    10
5     2     5    10     4     2
6     2    12     7    10     5
```

Since you mentioned that there are always 2 rows of identical Id you can also use it for any many Ids and rows as possible.